# How to limit the result of the pipeline according to a date, week and month range?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a pipeline that gives me the result according to the players belonging to a certain company in a daily, weekly, and monthly manner. I have a date filter in the dashboard which gives an iso date range. I want to limit or range my results according to the date filter? is there any way to do it in the pipeline?

```
  if (chartType === 'Daily') {
    statsPipelineCondition = {
      _id: { day: { $dayOfMonth: '$createdAt' }, month: { $month: '$createdAt' }, year: { $year: '$createdAt' } },
    };
    sortCondition = { '_id.year': 1, '_id.month': 1, '_id.day': 1 };
  } else if (chartType === 'Monthly') {
    statsPipelineCondition = {
      _id: { month: { $month: '$createdAt' }, year: { $year: '$createdAt' } },
    };
    sortCondition = { '_id.year': 1, '_id.month': 1 };
  } else {
    statsPipelineCondition = {
      _id: { week: { $week: '$createdAt' }, year: { $year: '$createdAt' } },
    };
    sortCondition = { '_id.year': 1, '_id.week': 1 };
  }

  const statsPipeline = [
    {
      $group: {
        ...statsPipelineCondition,
        TOTAL: { $sum: 1 },
        XR: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: ['$company', ['XR', 'CR', 'DX']] }, 1, 0] } },
        CT: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$company', 'CT'] }, 1, 0] } },
        MR: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$company', 'MR'] }, 1, 0] } },
        MG: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: ['$company', ['NM', 'MM', 'MG']] }, 1, 0] } },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        ...sortCondition,
      },
    },
  ];
```

Date filter:

```
datefilter -  { '$gte': '2020-09-01T04:49:50.899Z',
  '$lte': '2020-11-03T04:49:50.899Z' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So for some reason. MongoDB doesn't like dates in strings. It would be much better if we just convert the strings by an operator provided by the aggregation framework and this will make the things work.

```
{
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            {
              $gte: [
                '$createdAt',
                {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: dateFilter.$gte,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              $lte: [
                '$createdAt',
                {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: dateFilter.$lte,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `$match` stage prior to the `$group` stage to filter our based on the range:

```
let datefilter =  {
    '$gte': new Date('2020-09-01T04:49:50.899Z'),
    '$lte': new Date('2020-11-03T04:49:50.899Z') 
};

const statsPipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            createdAt: datefilter
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            ...statsPipelineCondition,
            TOTAL: { $sum: 1 },
            XR: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: ['$company', ['XR', 'CR', 'DX']] }, 1, 0] } },
            CT: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$company', 'CT'] }, 1, 0] } },
            MR: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$company', 'MR'] }, 1, 0] } },
            MG: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: ['$company', ['NM', 'MM', 'MG']] }, 1, 0] } },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            ...sortCondition,
        },
    },
];
```

Comment: I'm trying it in compass but seems like it's not working. It isn't giving any documents in the next stage. https://paste.pics/f9e1d861ad43eed6db3c8753e06de4af

Comment: Okay, so it's somehow not accepting the dates in strings, i have a function here 
`const getDateFilterFromParams = (params) => {
  let dateFilter;
  if (params.$and) {
    params.$and.forEach((o) => {
      if (Object.keys(o)[0] === 'createdAt') {
        dateFilter = o.createdAt;
      }
    });
  } else if (params.createdAt) {
    dateFilter = params.createdAt;
  }
  return dateFilter;
};`
What changes should make here in order to get the date object? Cause when i changed it into ISODate() this worked and returned me records.